# Google Speech Recognition module throws error when I try it out

Tags: python, speech-recognition, alsa

I am working on a project in which I need to take input from my built-in microphone and process it in Python. The input will be a command, like "right", "left", "forward", etc.

I found the speech recognition library [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/).

When I run the command `python -m speech_recognition`, I get the following output:

```
A moment of silence, please...
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:614:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1024:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2267:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2267:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2267:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1024:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot lock down 82274202 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Set minimum energy threshold to 48.5477227879
Say something!
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:614:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1024:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2267:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2267:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2267:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1024:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/speech_recognition /__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
with m as source: audio = r.listen(source)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 377, in listen
    buffer = source.stream.read(source.CHUNK, exception_on_overflow = False)
TypeError: read() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exception_on_overflow'
```

Comment: Looks like a permissions issue.  Are you in the `audio` group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that your pyaudio is too old. The speech_recognition module expects very recent API from PyAudio 0.2.9, your have an older version. Upgrade Pyaudio and error will go away.